# Expected Value Coin Flipping

Tags: logic

Consider the experiment of keeping flipping a fair coin until two heads are flipped consecutively. The outcome is the sequence of the flipped result. Possible examples of the outcome include HTHTHH and TTTHTHTTHH. The random variable X is defined to be the number of flips of an outcome. For example,  and X(HTHTHH)=6 and X(TTTHTHTTHH)=10. Find E(X).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be the number of expected flips to get heads.

If you flip a tails, you have made one flip, and you still expect to flip x more times.

If you flip heads, you are close to being done.  But if you flip HT you are back to square one and x flips away.

If you flip HH you are done.

$x = \frac 12 (x+1) + \frac 14 (x+2) + \frac 14 (2)$

Comment: Ummm... what about HTHTHTHTHTH?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork for every long one like that you have a short one like THH to balance out the average to 6.

Comment: But "balancing out" means they must have precisely the same *probability* of occurring.